# Cannot resize UITableView xcode 4.5.1 IOS 5.0

Tags: uitableview, resize

First off, believe me when I say I have tried all of the suggestions.  But I am willing to try them again, so feel free to comment/answer.  Currently my code looks like:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(tblView.frame.origin.x, tblView.frame.origin.y, tblView.frame.size.width, tblView.contentSize.height);

    [tblView setFrame:frame];
    [tblView reloadData];

    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews)
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);

    [scrollView setContentSize:contentRect.size];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
}
```

My @interface is:

```
@interface VH_HotelsListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
    NSMutableArray *hotelArray;
}
```

I have tied my storyboard table view into the tblView above. My table view is populated at run time from my database, so I know there are no issues there.

As you can see from above, I am getting the content size of the table view and trying to adjust the frame to the same height.  I am accurately getting the content size, though, because it resizes my scroll view to that height.  It just does nothing to the table view, unfortunately.  Though if I `NSLog(@"Table View Height: %g", tblView.frame.size.height)` just after setting it, I get the same number as for the content size `Table View Height: 3166`.  So it's like it's working, but it's not actually expanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got no answers, so I've updated my project.  I've taken the `UITableView` out of my storyboard altogether and now just create it in code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
    tblView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 500) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tblView.dataSource = self;
    tblView.delegate = self;

    [scrollView addSubview:tblView];
}
```

Then in `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(tblView.frame.origin.x, tblView.frame.origin.y, tblView.frame.size.width, tblView.contentSize.height);
    tblView.frame = frame;
    [tblView reloadData];
}
```

This seems to be working.